# Application error on Heroku but working fine locally

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

My application using node.js and express is working OK in the local host. I can deploy to Heroku successfully, but then I get an Application Error and the app doesn't run on Heroku.

This is what I get with heroku logs --tail:

```
$ npm start

> note-taker@1.0.0 start C:\Users\CAD\bootcamp\homework\note-taker
> node server.js

events.js:287
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1313:16)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1361:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1449:7)
    at Function.listen (C:\Users\CAD\bootcamp\homework\note-taker\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\CAD\bootcamp\homework\note-taker\server.js:25:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1340:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 3000
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! note-taker@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the note-taker@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

What could be causing this? I've been trying for days, following all Heroku guides, without success

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to listen on any port on heroku when a web port 80 is already in use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43944929/how-to-listen-on-any-port-on-heroku-when-a-web-port-80-is-already-in-use)

Answer (score 0):

The error is showing that the port is already in use, try to change the port and try.

ERROR:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I changed the port, but still get the application error and it doesn't run

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue!

The case in one of the filenames was changed locally to capitalize a letter, but github doesn't recognize case changes once the app is created, so it keep the original name. Just updating Github with the correct casing solved the issue.